# Showing $|\pi(1,n)|=O({n\over \log n})$ using the inequality $\prod_{p\in \pi(1,n)}{p}\le 4^n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Show $|\pi(1,n)|=O({n\over \log n})$ using the inequality $\prod_{p\in \pi(1,n)}{p}\le 4^n$. I came by other questions similar to it, but non seemed to be using the above fact, nor did I manage make the connection myself. I could really use a hand.

Remarks: $\pi(1,n)$ is the set containing all prime numbers between 1 and $n$.

Comment: Will this help https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/pdf/bertrand.pdf?